# Commerce + Views: Distinct on Referenced Product not working

Tags: 7, commerce, views

I have a Product Display node view which ignores distinct on the query. The goal is to avoid displaying multiple product displays which refer to same Product SKU. I created a relation with the Referenced Product but this did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this in filter.

Content: Product Reference:delta (= 0)

which will show only one variation of your product.